# Problems with AutoPanning in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, popup

I've built a simple Leaflet map with Popups showing some information. Most of the time the Autopanning works just as intended and the map moves to show the whole content of the popup, but sometimes it doesn't (See Screenshot). I can not find the cause of this, as it seems to happen randomly. Does anyone have a tip of what could be causing this?

[image: Screenshot]

[image]

```
    var southWest = L.latLng(27, -15);
    var northEast = L.latLng(73, 41);
    var  mybounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
    var map = L.map('map',{zoomControl: false}).setView([47.74739, 13], 4);
    map.options.minZoom = 4;
    map.options.maxZoom = 14;
    
    var Tile = L.tileLayer('https://a.tile.openstreetmap.de/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {

        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a 
            href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>' ,
        id: 'mapbox/light-v9',
        tileSize: 256,
        zoomOffset: 0,

    });
    map.setMaxBounds(mybounds);

  function forEachFeatureCC(feature, layer) {

            var popUp = "<b>"+feature.properties.name+"</b>" + "<br>"+
                 feature.properties.FotoRechte +"<br>"+
                "<img src='"+ feature.properties.URLfoto +"'width='300'</img>" +"<br>"+
                "<a href='"+feature.properties.URLsite+"'target='_top'>"+feature.properties.URLtext+"</a>";

            layer.bindPopup(popUp);

        }
```

Comment: It's not random, your setting `map.setMaxBounds(mybounds);` prevents popup auto pan if that would put map out of bounds.

Comment: That was my first guess, too. But by multiple clicking the marker from above, the popup opens as intendet ( I added another screenshot). Sometimes it works properly on the first click, sometimes not. The problem occurs even if I disable the maxBounds.

Comment: Race condition. The image isn't loaded when the popup is shown, so it has a height of zero. It loads some milliseconds later, well after the panning logic has run.

Comment: This does make sense. Any ideas on how to prevent this?

Comment: You could use popup `.update()` method. Leaflet docs say: _Updates the popup content, layout and position. Useful for updating the popup after something inside changed, e.g. image loaded._

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't know that yet. In the meantime I made a dirty workaround by making a css rule for the popups. So the auto panning works regardles of the image loading progress. But I will try to implement your suggested method, surely it is the better option.